# How to catch JSON Array value in Swagger (PowerApps)

Tags: arrays, json, swagger

I need some help on this, I would like to pass a bulk record to my application in one shot using JSON, but i got error when parsing it to Swagger.

Any luck?

**Here is my JSON (It's from PowerApps converted to JSON)
---------------**

```
[
  {
    "ItemId": "2HPB110X-V02",
    "TransferId": "TO-2008-000201"
  },
  {
    "ItemId": "2HPB85X-V02",
    "TransferId": "TO-2008-000201"
  },
  {
    "ItemId": "2HPB134X-V02",
    "TransferId": "TO-2008-000201"
  },
  {
    "ItemId": "2HPB134X-V02",
    "TransferId": "TO-2008-000201"
  }
]
```

### My Webservice required to pass like this. (Expected Output from SWAGGER)

```
{
  "record": [
    {
      "ItemId": "2HPB110X-V02",
      "TransferId": "TO-2008-000201"
    },
    {
      "ItemId": "2HPB85X-V02",
      "TransferId": "TO-2008-000201"
    },
    {
      "ItemId": "2HPB134X-V02",
      "TransferId": "TO-2008-000201"
    },
    {
      "ItemId": "2HPB134X-V02",
      "TransferId": "TO-2008-000201"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Here is my Swagger:
--------------------**

```
/api/services/XXXXXServiceGroup/XXXXXService/TestBulkInsertList:
    post:
      responses:
        '200':
          description: Success
          schema: {type: string, title: Message}
      summary: TestBulkInsertList
      operationId: TestBulkInsertList
      parameters:
      - {name: Content-Type, in: header, required: true, type: string, default: application/json}
      - name: body
        in: body
        required: true
        schema:
          type: array
          maxItems: 20
          items: {$ref: '#/definitions/shipNowData'}
definitions:
  shipNowData:
    type: object
    properties:
      transferId: {type: string}
      itemId: {type: string}
    xml: {name: record}
parameters: {}
responses: {}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Found it:**

```
/api/services/XXXXXServiceGroup/XXXXXService/TestBulkInsertList:
    post:
      responses:
        '200':
          description: Success
          schema: {type: string, title: Message}
      summary: TestBulkInsertList
      operationId: TestBulkInsertList
      parameters:
      - {name: Content-Type, in: header, required: true, type: string, default: application/json}
      - name: body
        in: body
        required: true
        schema:
          type: object
          properties:
            record:
              type: array
              items: {$ref: '#/definitions/shipNowData'}
      description: TestBulkInsertList
definitions:
  shipNowData:
    type: object
    properties:
      transferId: {type: string}
      itemId: {type: string}
    xml: {name: record}
parameters: {}
responses: {}
```